# Showing a function does not have a local max or min

Tags: real-analysis

The function is

$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
 0  & \text{if $x = 0$} \end{cases} $

I have proved that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, and  $f^{'}(0) = 0$.

Now I have to show that $f$ has neither a local max nor local min at $0$. 
I know that by showing that if there is no sign change around $0$, then $f$ has no local max or min.

However, I are there other ways to prove this? I was thinking about how if proving if $f$ is either increasing, decreasing, or constant around $0$, then $f$ does not have any local max or min at $0$ .

Comment: If there is no sign change in $f(x)$ than you either have a maximum or a minimum in your case

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this simple by the definition of the local extrema. Function does have a local extrema at the point $x \in X$ if there is a neighbourhood $V$, such that $f(x)$ is either the minimum of $f(V)$ or the maximum of $f(V)$.

Let $S_\delta(x) = \{ y \mid |y_i - x_i| \leq \delta \}$.

You can show, that for any $\delta > 0, \ f(S_\delta(x))$ will contain both strictly positive and strictly negative values?

Comment: So, by proving that since, for any $\delta \gt 0$, $f(S_\delta(x))$ contains both strictly positive and negative values, it is possible to say that $f$ does not have either local maxima or minima?

Comment: No, but $f$ is differentiable at 0 and its derivative at 0 is 0. If the function $f$ had an extremum at 0, its value would be equal to 0. Thus, proving the function has both strictly positive and strictly negative values for each neighbourhood of 0 gives you, that 0 is not a local extrema.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(\frac 2 {(2n+1) \pi})=(\frac 2  {(2n+1) \pi} )^{2} (-1)^{n}$. You can see that every interval around $0$ has points where the value of $f$ is greater than $f(0)$ and points where the value of $f$ is less than $f(0)$.

Comment: I apologize first, but I don't quite understand the answer. So does this imply that if there are points around $0$ where the value of $f$ is both greater and lower than $f(0)$, then $f$ has neither local maxima nor minima?

Comment: Isn't this clear from definition of local maximum and local minimum? If $f$ has local maximum at $0$ there there exists $r>0$ such that $f(x) \leq f(0)$ for all $x \in (-r,r)$. I have shown that there is always some $x$ in this interval such that $f(x) >f(0)$ so we have a contradiction.